# Mimic a CTRL+A keypress event in bash without using expect

Tags: bash, redirect, key, keypress

How can I redirect a CTRL+A keypress event to a program through bash? I can not use expect or other applications not already present in standard linux distributions.

Requirement: bash? gedit 1.txt < (send CTRL+A character)

Comment: Tell us some more about what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Gedit is a graphical program for editing text files, and if you're trying to do something inside of a shell script to manipulate the text in a file, there are a bazillion better tools for it.

Comment: gedit is just an example i have used here. I want to mimic a keypress event for any application like realplayer < (keyboard shortcut for play button). I hope my question is clear.

Comment: It's likely that you would need to use [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) or something similar for this.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's possible depends on the program, what toolkit it was written in and whether or not the program and/or its toolkit supports being commanded externally.  Most GUI'd programs don't, largely because users get disconcerted when their applications start doing things automagically.

You might check if your application is available as a library that will let you build a headless program that you can command by whatever means you want instead of trying to send events to its GUI.